# Kotlin version 1.1.4-eap-77 is not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, updates

I started a new app in Kotlin, but when Android Studio finished to build the new project, etc.. is says that cand download the correct version of Kotlin:

[image]

Here is the build gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-eap-77'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

How can I fix it to allow download the correct version?

Comment: Kotlin 1.1.4 has already been released; there is absolutely no need to use a EAP version at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **use a EAP version** of the kotlin plugin you have to add the repo in the `buildscript` block

```
maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1'
      }
```

Something like:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-eap-77'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
              url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1'
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Also you should add the same maven repo to `repository` block to download the kotlin dependencies.

Something like:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1'
    }
}
```

You can find more [info here.](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-1-1-4-eap/3721)

Comment: Thanks, but is not working. I put as your example but still don't load the repo.

Comment: @Shudy I've updated the answer with the right url (it was wrong) . I've just checked and it exists: https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.4-eap-77/